# Clever method to integrate $ \int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}}\,dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm curious in knowing if there is any other method to solve this indefinite integral
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}}\,dx 
$$

besides set $ \sqrt{x} = t $ and obtain
$$
\int \frac{2t^{2}}{1+t^{4}}\,dt 
$$
where I reduce the problem to
$$
\int \frac{t^{2}}{1+t^{4}}\,dt 
$$
and factorize $1+t^{4}=(t^{2}+\sqrt{2}t+1)(t^{2}-\sqrt{2}t+1)$
to reduce the integral to

$$
\int \frac{t^{2}}{(t^{2}+\sqrt{2}t+1)(t^{2}-\sqrt{2}t+1)}\,dt 
$$
This is not impossible with partial fraction but rather tedious.

Comment: Your factorisation of $1+t^4$ is wrong.

Comment: The square on the terms with the square root of two should not be there. Otherwise it is correct. It should be: $$\int \frac{t^{2}}{(t^{2}+\sqrt{2}t+1)\cdot(t^{2}-\sqrt{2}t+1)}\,dt $$

Comment: I'm sorry, i copied and pasted, didn't realize

Comment: Now is correct, i think

Comment: The following result is rather lovely : $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: A fairly nice way to evaluate the definite version of the $t$ integral is via the substitution $u=1/t$. This gets you $1/(1+u^4)$ as the integrand, and you can combine the integrals nicely to continue.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a shortcut

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}}\,dx 
&= \int \frac{\frac1{\sqrt{x}}}{x+\frac1x}\,dx 
=\int \frac{d(\sqrt x- \frac1{\sqrt{x}}) + d(\sqrt x+\frac1{\sqrt{x}}) }{x+\frac1x}\\
&= \int \frac{d(\sqrt x- \frac1{\sqrt{x}}) }{(\sqrt x-\frac1{\sqrt x})^2+2} +\int \frac{d(\sqrt x+\frac1{\sqrt{x}}) }{(\sqrt x+\frac1{\sqrt x})^2-2}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\frac{ \sqrt x-\frac1{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt2}
-\frac1{\sqrt2}\coth^{-1}\frac{ \sqrt x +\frac1{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt2}+C
\end{align}

Comment: Sir/Lady where can I learn such trick? Only through experience and intuition provided me by me genoma? I'm pretty new on this site so i don't know if is off topic but could you advise me a good exercise book that can help me improve my eye on particular situation such this and my skill with integral? (Sorry if is off topic)

Comment: Like here is not such a complex trick, but i never divided both numerator and denominator in a integral before. I know i sound like a newbie but i want to understand and learn as much as possible

Comment: @Raff - The so-called ‘tricks’, such as what is employed here, are applicable to integrands of particular structures; they normally do not work on others, which might be the reason that they are usually not taught in standard calculus, but instead circulated in places like here. I’m unaware of any dedicated books to expose to those off methods, You accumulate them from seeing enough and applying them yourself ...

Comment: @Raff - Here are a couple of more which are relatively simple and you could find on this site. $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(-\ln x\right)^2dx=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\int_{0}^{1} x^t dx\right)\bigg|_{t=0}
= \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\frac1{t+1}\right) \bigg|_{t=0} =2
$$ $$\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{\ln x} dx=\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^t dt dx = \int_0^1 \frac1{t+1}dt= \ln 2$$

Comment: thanks for the answer @Quanto